# Find and replace both open and close tag with new tags

Tags: xml, xhtml, text-editor

I have a bunch of repeated code sitewide on div's that I'd like to replace with another tag.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!loadingText">
   <label>Status</label>
   <div class="form-control" ng-if="request.RequestStatus">
      {{ request.RequestStatus }}
   </div>
</div>
```

What would be a good way though out the site to replace the opening and closing `div` tags that match `<div class="form-group" ng-show="!loadingText">`, while preserving the content between the tags?

The replacement that I'm looking to do would be result in the following:

```
<fg>
   <label>Status</label>
   <div class="form-control" ng-if="request.RequestStatus">
      {{ request.RequestStatus }}
   </div>
</fg>
```

Comment: replace with what? and did you try something?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I'd expect that finding the correct closing tag would be complex,

Comment: @EvenMien It is somewhat complex if you want to do it wih regex. Does the input qualify as well-formed HTML or even XML?

Comment: For this, you can assume XML. It does not have to be done in regex. That was just the first tool I thought of using. I'll retag.

Comment: Yes it is a bit complex with regex.. you can try a DOM parser

Comment: @EvenMien If your input is actual XHMTL, my solution below needs the XHTML namespace as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input qualifies as XML, this is a no-brainer in XSLT.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!loadingText">
   <label>Status</label>
   <div class="form-control" ng-if="request.RequestStatus">
      {{ request.RequestStatus }}
   </div>
</div>
```

when passed through this XSLT 1.0 transformation

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- identity template: copies everything that fits no other template -->    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- specific <div> nodes will replaced by <fg> -->
    <xsl:template match="div[@class='form-group' and @ng-show='!loadingText']">
        <fg>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </fg>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

becomes

```
<fg>
   <label>Status</label>
   <div class="form-control" ng-if="request.RequestStatus">
      {{ request.RequestStatus }}
   </div>
</fg>
```

Command line tools like `xsltproc` can do the work easily.